# Validação dos campos e dados na table não funcionam

Tags: javascript, jquery, front-end

Estou querendo fazer a validação dos campos se estão devidamente preenchidos e verificar se a soma dos campos for maior que 10 e mostrar os dados na table mas nada disso está acontecendo.

Se eu deixo os campos vazios e tento clicar em <kbd>cadastrar</kbd>, em vez de mostrar a mensagem que os campos estão vazios, ele mostra esta mensagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**HTML:**

```
<form action="" method="post" class="formcss" name="form1"  >
    <h1>Dados do Aluno<br/>

    </h1> 
    <div>&nbsp;</div> 
    <div>
        <div class="rotulos">RGM :</div>
        <input id="rgm" type="text" name="rgm" placeholder="Digite seu RGM" class="entrada" />
    </div>
    <div>
    <div>
        <div class="rotulos">Nome :</div>
        <input id="nome" type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Nome completo" class="entrada" />
    </div>

    <div>
        <div class="rotulos">Nota parcial :</div>
        <input type="text" id="notaparcial" name="notaparcial" 
               placeholder="Digite aqui a nota parcial" class="entrada" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="rotulos">Nota exercícios :</div>
        <input type="text" id="notaexercicios" name="notaexercicios" 
               placeholder="Digite aqui a nota dos exercícios" class="entrada" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="rotulos">Nota projeto :</div>
        <input type="text" id="notaprojeto" name="notaprojeto" 
               placeholder="Digite aqui a nota no projeto" class="entrada" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="rotulos">Nota regimental :</div>
        <input type="text" id="notaregimental" name="notaregimental" 
               placeholder="Digite aqui a nota regimental" class="entrada" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="rotulos">&nbsp;</div>
        <input type="button" id="btncalcular" value="Calcular" class="botao" />
        <input type="button" id="btnlistar" value="Mostrar" class="botao" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <div id="divresultado" class="rotuloretorno">Resultado...</div>
    </div>
    <div>&nbsp;</div><br>
</form>
```

**CSS:**

```
.formcss {
   width: 55%;
   background-color: #865027;
   padding: 20px 30px 20px 30px;
   font-size: 12px;
   font-family: verdana;
   color: #fff;
   text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000;
   border-radius: 25px;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
h1 {
   padding: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
   border-bottom: 3px solid #000;
   text-align: center;
}
.titulo {    
   font-size: 11px;
}
div {    
   margin: 0px 0px 20px;
}
.rotulos {
   float: left;
   width: 20%;
   text-align: right;
   padding-right: 10px;
   margin-top: 10px;
   font-weight: bold;
}
.rotuloretorno {
   float: left;
   width: 75%;
   font-size: 14px;
   font-family: verdana;
   text-align: left;
   padding-left: 200px;
   padding-right: 10px;
   margin-top: 10px;
   font-weight: bold;
}
.entrada {
   border: none;
   color: #525252;
   height: 30px;
   line-height: 15px;    
   padding: 5px 0px 5px 5px;
   width: 70%;
   border-radius: 5px;
   box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000;
   background-color: #f5deb3;
}
.botao {
   background-color: #2e1707;
   border: none;
   padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;
   color: #fff;
   border-radius: 4px;
   text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #FFE477;
   font-weight: bold;
   box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #3D3D3D;
}
.botao:hover {
   color: #dbd9d9;
   background-color: #030201;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function validar() {
   var nome = $("#nome").val();
   var rgm = $("#rgm").val();
   var parcial = $("#notaparcial").val();
   var exercicios = $("#notaexercicios").val();
   var projeto = $("#notaprojeto").val();
   var regimental = $("#notaregimental").val();

   if (nome == "") {
      alert('Preencha o campo com seu nome');
      form1.nome.focus();
      return false;
   } else if (rgm == "") {
      alert('Preencha o campo com rgm');
      form1.rgm.focus();
      return false;

   } else if (parcial == "") {
      alert('Preencha o campo com a nota da parcial');
      form1.notaparcial.focus();
      return false;

   } else if (exercicios == "") {
      alert('Preencha o campo com a nota dos exe');
      form1.notaexercicios.focus();
      return false;

   } else if (projeto == "") {
      alert('Preencha o campo com a nota projeto');
      form1.notaprojeto.focus();
      return false;

   } else if (regimental == ""){
      alert('Preencha o campo com a nota regimental');
      form1.notaregimental.focus();
      return false;
   }
   return true;
}

function caculoMedia( /* n1, n2, n3, n4, etc */ ) {
   return [].reduce.call(arguments, function(sum, nr) {
      return sum + nr;
   }, 0) / (arguments.length);
}

function situacao(n1, n2, n3, n4) {
   var situacao = "";
   var media = caculoMedia(n1, n2, n3, n4);
   if (media >= 6) situacao += "Aprovado";
   else if (media < 6) situacao += "Exame";
   else situacao += "Reprovado";
   return situacao;
}

var nomes = [];
var indice = [];
var sit = [];
var media = [];

var i = 1;

window.onload = function() {
   var btn = document.getElementById("btncalcular");
   btn.onclick = function() {
      if (validar()) {
         var parcial = parseFloat($("#notaparcial").val());
         var exercicios = parseFloat($("#notaexercicios").val());
         var projeto =parseFloat($("#notaprojeto").val());
         var regimental = parseFloat($("#notaregimental").val());
         console.log(parcial, exercicios, projeto, regimental);
         if (parcial + exercicios + projeto + regimental <= 10) {
            nomes[i] = $("#nome").val();

            var resp = caculoMedia(parcial, exercicios, projeto, regimental);
            media[i] = resp;
            var sit = situacao(parcial, exercicios, projeto, regimental);
            sit[i] = situacao;
         } else {
            alert("A soma das notas não podem ultrapassar 10");
         }
      }
   }
   document.getElementById("btnlistar").onclick = function() {
      listarAlunos();
   }
}

function listarAlunos() {
   var conteudo = "<table border='2'>";
   conteudo += "<tr>";
   conteudo += "<th>";
   conteudo += "<div class='aluno'><p>Aluno</p></div>";
   conteudo += "</th>";
   conteudo += "<th>";
   conteudo += "<div class='media'><p>Media</p></div>";
   conteudo += "</th>";
   conteudo += "<th>";
   conteudo += "<div class='situacao'><p>Situacao</p></div>";
   conteudo += "</th>";
   conteudo += "</tr>";
   //pos contator
   for (var pos = 0; pos < nomes.length; pos++) {
      conteudo += "<tr>";

      conteudo += "<td>" + nomes[pos] + "</td>";
      conteudo += "<td>" + media[pos] + "</td>";
      conteudo += "<td>" + sit[pos] + "</td>";

      conteudo += "</tr>";
   }
   conteudo += "</table>";
   document.getElementById("txtrelatorio").innerHTML = conteudo;
}
```

Comment: faz uso do html5.. adiciona aos inputs o campo required! 
<input type="text" name="usrname" required>

de resto, a resposta a tua pergunta já foi respondida, para chamar uma funcao tens que por os ()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu JavaScript possui muitos problemas que corrigi, como, por exemplo, a chamada da função `validar` no `if`, estava faltando os parênteses: `if(validar())`, entre outros erros que impediam o código funcionar (não vou explicar todos senão isso vai ficar enorme).

Segue o código corrigido (caso haja mais problemas, favor apontar para que possa ser corrigido):

```
<script>
function validar() {
   var nome = $("#nome").val();
   var rgm = $("#rgm").val();
   var parcial = $("#notaparcial").val();
   var exercicios = $("#notaexercicios").val();
   var projeto = $("#notaprojeto").val();
   var regimental = $("#notaregimental").val();

   if (nome == "") {
      alert('Preencha o campo com seu nome');
      form1.nome.focus();
      return false;
   } else if (rgm == "") {
      alert('Preencha o campo com rgm');
      form1.rgm.focus();
      return false;

   } else if (parcial == "") {
      alert('Preencha o campo com a nota da parcial');
      form1.notaparcial.focus();
      return false;

   } else if (exercicios == "") {
      alert('Preencha o campo com a nota dos exe');
      form1.notaexercicios.focus();
      return false;

   } else if (projeto == "") {
      alert('Preencha o campo com a nota projeto');
      form1.notaprojeto.focus();
      return false;

   } else if (regimental == ""){
      alert('Preencha o campo com a nota regimental');
      form1.notaregimental.focus();
      return false;
   }
   return true;
}

function caculoMedia( n1, n2, n3, n4, etc ) {
   return [].reduce.call(arguments, function(sum, nr) {
      return sum + nr;
   }, 0) / (arguments.length);
}

function situacao(n1, n2, n3, n4) {
   var situacao = "";
   var media = caculoMedia(n1, n2, n3, n4);
   if (media >= 6) situacao += "Aprovado";
   else if (media < 6) situacao += "Exame";
   else situacao += "Reprovado";
   return situacao;
}

var nomes = [];
var indice = [];
var sit = [];
var media = [];

var i = 0;

window.onload = function() {
   var btn = $("#btncalcular");
   btn.click(function() {
      if (validar()) {
         var parcial = parseFloat($("#notaparcial").val());
         var exercicios = parseFloat($("#notaexercicios").val());
         var projeto =parseFloat($("#notaprojeto").val());
         var regimental = parseFloat($("#notaregimental").val());
         console.log(parcial, exercicios, projeto, regimental);
         if (parcial + exercicios + projeto + regimental <= 10) {
            nomes[i] = $("#nome").val();

            var resp = caculoMedia(parcial, exercicios, projeto, regimental);
            media[i] = resp;
            var situa = situacao(parcial, exercicios, projeto, regimental);
            sit[i] = situa;
         } else {
            alert("A soma das notas não podem ultrapassar 10");
         }
      }
   });
   $("#btnlistar").click(listarAlunos);
}

function listarAlunos() {
   var conteudo = "<table border='2'>";
   conteudo += "<tr>";
   conteudo += "<th>";
   conteudo += "<div class='aluno'><p>Aluno</p></div>";
   conteudo += "</th>";
   conteudo += "<th>";
   conteudo += "<div class='media'><p>Media</p></div>";
   conteudo += "</th>";
   conteudo += "<th>";
   conteudo += "<div class='situacao'><p>Situacao</p></div>";
   conteudo += "</th>";
   conteudo += "</tr>";
   //pos contator
   for (var pos = 0; pos < nomes.length; pos++) {
      conteudo += "<tr>";

      conteudo += "<td>" + nomes[pos] + "</td>";
      conteudo += "<td>" + media[pos] + "</td>";
      conteudo += "<td>" + sit[0] + "</td>";

      conteudo += "</tr>";
   }
   conteudo += "</table>";
   $("#divresultado").html(conteudo);
}
</script>
```

Outra coisa, nesta linha `document.getElementById("txtrelatorio").innerHTML = conteudo;`, verifiquei que no seu HTML não existe o elemento com o `id="txtrelatorio"`. Imagino que você queira se referir à `div` com `id="divresultado"`. Se for isso, basta substituir no script.

**Outra sugestão:** já que usa jQuery, use-o em todo o código. Por exemplo, `document.getElementById("txtrelatorio").innerHTML = conteudo;` poderia ser `$("#txtrelatorio").html(conteudo);`.

```js
function validar() {
   var nome = $("#nome").val();
   var rgm = $("#rgm").val();
   var parcial = $("#notaparcial").val();
   var exercicios = $("#notaexercicios").val();
   var projeto = $("#notaprojeto").val();
   var regimental = $("#notaregimental").val();

   if (nome == "") {
      alert('Preencha o campo com seu nome');
      form1.nome.focus();
      return false;
   } else if (rgm == "") {
      alert('Preencha o campo com rgm');
      form1.rgm.focus();
      return false;

   } else if (parcial == "") {
      alert('Preencha o campo com a nota da parcial');
      form1.notaparcial.focus();
      return false;

   } else if (exercicios == "") {
      alert('Preencha o campo com a nota dos exe');
      form1.notaexercicios.focus();
      return false;

   } else if (projeto == "") {
      alert('Preencha o campo com a nota projeto');
      form1.notaprojeto.focus();
      return false;

   } else if (regimental == ""){
      alert('Preencha o campo com a nota regimental');
      form1.notaregimental.focus();
      return false;
   }
   return true;
}

function caculoMedia( n1, n2, n3, n4, etc ) {
   return [].reduce.call(arguments, function(sum, nr) {
      return sum + nr;
   }, 0) / (arguments.length);
}

function situacao(n1, n2, n3, n4) {
   var situacao = "";
   var media = caculoMedia(n1, n2, n3, n4);
   if (media >= 6) situacao += "Aprovado";
   else if (media < 6) situacao += "Exame";
   else situacao += "Reprovado";
   return situacao;
}

var nomes = [];
var indice = [];
var sit = [];
var media = [];

var i = 0;

window.onload = function() {
   var btn = $("#btncalcular");
   btn.click(function() {
      if (validar()) {
         var parcial = parseFloat($("#notaparcial").val());
         var exercicios = parseFloat($("#notaexercicios").val());
         var projeto =parseFloat($("#notaprojeto").val());
         var regimental = parseFloat($("#notaregimental").val());
         console.log(parcial, exercicios, projeto, regimental);
         if (parcial + exercicios + projeto + regimental <= 10) {
            nomes[i] = $("#nome").val();

            var resp = caculoMedia(parcial, exercicios, projeto, regimental);
            media[i] = resp;
            var situa = situacao(parcial, exercicios, projeto, regimental);
            sit[i] = situa;
         } else {
            alert("A soma das notas não podem ultrapassar 10");
         }
      }
   });
   $("#btnlistar").click(listarAlunos);
}

function listarAlunos() {
   var conteudo = "<table border='2'>";
   conteudo += "<tr>";
   conteudo += "<th>";
   conteudo += "<div class='aluno'><p>Aluno</p></div>";
   conteudo += "</th>";
   conteudo += "<th>";
   conteudo += "<div class='media'><p>Media</p></div>";
   conteudo += "</th>";
   conteudo += "<th>";
   conteudo += "<div class='situacao'><p>Situacao</p></div>";
   conteudo += "</th>";
   conteudo += "</tr>";
   //pos contator
   for (var pos = 0; pos < nomes.length; pos++) {
      conteudo += "<tr>";

      conteudo += "<td>" + nomes[pos] + "</td>";
      conteudo += "<td>" + media[pos] + "</td>";
      conteudo += "<td>" + sit[0] + "</td>";

      conteudo += "</tr>";
   }
   conteudo += "</table>";
   $("#divresultado").html(conteudo);
}
```

```css
.formcss {
   width: 55%;
   background-color: #865027;
   padding: 20px 30px 20px 30px;
   font-size: 12px;
   font-family: verdana;
   color: #fff;
   text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000;
   border-radius: 25px;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
h1 {
   padding: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
   border-bottom: 3px solid #000;
   text-align: center;
}
.titulo {    
   font-size: 11px;
}
div {    
   margin: 0px 0px 20px;
}
.rotulos {
   float: left;
   width: 20%;
   text-align: right;
   padding-right: 10px;
   margin-top: 10px;
   font-weight: bold;
}
.rotuloretorno {
   float: left;
   width: 75%;
   font-size: 14px;
   font-family: verdana;
   text-align: left;
   padding-left: 200px;
   padding-right: 10px;
   margin-top: 10px;
   font-weight: bold;
}
.entrada {
   border: none;
   color: #525252;
   height: 30px;
   line-height: 15px;    
   padding: 5px 0px 5px 5px;
   width: 70%;
   border-radius: 5px;
   box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000;
   background-color: #f5deb3;
}
.botao {
   background-color: #2e1707;
   border: none;
   padding: 10px 25px 10px 25px;
   color: #fff;
   border-radius: 4px;
   text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #FFE477;
   font-weight: bold;
   box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #3D3D3D;
}
.botao:hover {
   color: #dbd9d9;
   background-color: #030201;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post" class="formcss" name="form1"  >
    <h1>Dados do Aluno<br/>

    </h1> 
    <div>&nbsp;</div> 
    <div>
        <div class="rotulos">RGM :</div>
        <input id="rgm" type="text" name="rgm" placeholder="Digite seu RGM" class="entrada" />
    </div>
    <div>
    <div>
        <div class="rotulos">Nome :</div>
        <input id="nome" type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Nome completo" class="entrada" />
    </div>

    <div>
        <div class="rotulos">Nota parcial :</div>
        <input type="text" id="notaparcial" name="notaparcial" 
               placeholder="Digite aqui a nota parcial" class="entrada" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="rotulos">Nota exercícios :</div>
        <input type="text" id="notaexercicios" name="notaexercicios" 
               placeholder="Digite aqui a nota dos exercícios" class="entrada" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="rotulos">Nota projeto :</div>
        <input type="text" id="notaprojeto" name="notaprojeto" 
               placeholder="Digite aqui a nota no projeto" class="entrada" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="rotulos">Nota regimental :</div>
        <input type="text" id="notaregimental" name="notaregimental" 
               placeholder="Digite aqui a nota regimental" class="entrada" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="rotulos">&nbsp;</div>
        <input type="button" id="btncalcular" value="Calcular" class="botao" />
        <input type="button" id="btnlistar" value="Mostrar" class="botao" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <div id="divresultado" class="rotuloretorno">Resultado...</div>
    </div>
    <div>&nbsp;</div><br>
</form>
```

Comment: Dvd agora funcionou, mas agora ao cadastrar o aluno com a média ele não mostra a situação na table , em que era pra mostrar se o aluno esta aprovado,reprovado ou exame

Comment: @User1999 Dá uma olhada no texto no final da resposta.

Comment: @User1999 Não está funcionando o lance do resultado. Vou ver aqui.

Comment: blz vou dar uma olhada

Comment: @User1999 Pronto. Coloquei o código todo corrigido. Tinha ainda muitos erros.